# Software/Product Recommendations

Tags: discussion

I am starting to see some Software Recommendations appearing on Freelancing, and I would like to know what the community thinks of it. Shopping questions (as described in the [StackExchange Blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)) are recommended as being off topic, as the answers can change over time, and it invites spam and other low-quality answers to the question.

The SE network already has a [Software Recommendations site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), and I feel that site would be better suited for these questions. Unfortunately, I'm not the only one allowed to make a decision here, so I'd like to know what the community feels should happen:

- Deny all questions asking specifically for a *product* instead of a *process*
- Allow the questions if they don't invite spam in

Comment: related: http://meta.freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/141/64

Comment: Some of these do well, some get spam. Some feel like they have a place. The one from the person who was using Excel templates for time tracking sort of spoke to me, because there was a time when that's how I was tracking time, until just recently.